# MongoDB : Querying collection within a Date Range

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in my mongodb with records in this format

```
 db.userlogins.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8c11f30bbf5bcba06f0"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-16 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8cf1f30bbf5bcba06f1"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-17 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8db1f30bbf5bcba06f2"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-18 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8e71f30bbf5bcba06f3"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-19 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8f21f30bbf5bcba06f4"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-20 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("519bb8fc1f30bbf5bcba06f5"),
        "userId" : "sai",
        "created_at" : "2013-05-21 10:31:02.765"
```

I was trying to find out users logged in with in a certian range

so i tried

```
db.userlogins.find({created_on: {$gte: "2013-05-17 10:31:02.765", $lt: "2013-05-21 10:31:02.765"}});
```

But dont know why its not returuning any data back ??
Could anybody please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
 db.userlogins.find({created_at: {$gte: "2013-05-17 10:31:02.765", $lt: "2013-05-21 10:31:02.765"}});
```